# What does __attribute__((constructor)) compile to for iOS? How to do it in hand-written asm?

Tags: ios, assembly, arm

For learning purposes I have been writing stuff in assembly. Currently I'm trying to do the equivalent of C's `__attribute__((constructor))` in assembly but I'm not sure how to do that.

So my question, what do attributes compile to? I understand some may be quite different so I'm mainly asking about constructor.

Comment: Ask your compiler to emit asm source. Constructor will likely place it into a special section and/or a function pointer table.

Comment: It depends entirely on which attribute; some of them are just about optimization of functions that call them e.g. `__attribute__((const))` means its a pure function that doesn't look at globals.  So you could still use that in the prototype for a hand-written function, if your hand-written function actually is safe to not call as many times as the source says.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Jester.

For my case (arm64 on iOS), it created a new section under `__DATA`.

```
.section __TEXT, __text, regular, pure_instructions
.global _constructor
.p2align 2
_constructor:
    ...
    ret

.section __DATA, __mod_init_func, mod_init_funcs
    .p2align 4
    .quad _constructor
```